# adding dc bias to my signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, bias

So I am having trouble understanding the following schematic. It is supposed to take an input through the capacitor C6 which is an AC sine wave and add a DC bias to it. However I do not understand how this circuit adds the DC bias. Can anyone explain?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyze the circuit with the capacitor C6 open (DC analysis) and you will see that it is a unity-gain buffer connected to the junction of R10/R11.

So, if they are both value R the voltage at the non-inverting input will be 10V with S1 closed, and the voltage at the output will also be +10V, ideally.

To the extent the circuit is linear (pretty good approximation until the op-amp saturates) the output will be the sum of the +10V and the AC-coupled input through C6. The gain from the latter node (right-hand side of C6) is -1, of course.

---

Note: from the **left** side of C6 it may have a gain of almost -1 or not, because we don't know what frequency the AC sine-wave input is nor the value of C6. If C6 is very large the gain will be close to -1. If the reactance of C6 (which is \$\frac{1}{\omega C_6}\$) starts to get comparable to the resistance of R9 the gain will become smaller in magnitude and the phase will lead the input by more and more, until at very low frequencies you have almost no AC voltage at the output and a phase shift of +\$\pi/2\$.

Comment: why would the output voltage of the op amp be +10V , can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The voltage at the non-inverting input is 20V*R11/(R10+R11) = 10V (assuming S1 closed). The voltage at the inverting input must also be 10V with the op-amp balanced. Since left end of R9 is hanging in the air, that means that the output must also be 10V. Unity gain from the inverting input and gain of +0.5 from the left side of R10.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Assuming switch S1 is closed:
$$V_a = 10 V = V_b$$
Suppose an AC voltage, V(t) is applied through capacitor now.

At node b, we can apply Kirchoff's Current Law.
Ideally, the current going into op-amp from node b = 0 Amps. Therefore:

$$(V(t)-V_b)/R = (V_b-V_o)/R$$
$$i.e., V_o = - V(t) + 2V_b  $$
$$= -V(t) + 20$$
20V is the DC bias obtained here.

Thus this cicuit adds a DC bias of $$V_{offset} = V_a(1+R_{12}/R_9)$$

Comment: I appreciate the maths , really helps to understand the output of the op amp and the addition of the dc bias. If I could like your answer I would (the reputation though...) haha

Answer (score 1):

This circuit does three things:

It inverts the AC input signal coming thru C6.

It amplifies the AC signal.  The amplification factor is R12 / R9.

It optionally adds a DC bias to the amplified signal, depending on switch S1.

The amplification factor is

Answer (score 0):

In your figure, assume an ideal op amp. Therefore, the voltage \$v_n\$ at the op amp's non-inverting input is given by equation (1):

$$
v_n = \frac{R11\,V_{CC}}{R10+R11}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
$$

Using nodal analysis, determine the voltage \$v_i\$ at the op amp's inverting input:

$$
\frac{v_{i}-v_{in}}{R9} + \frac{v_{i}-v_{o}}{R12} = 0
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)
\\[0.2in]
\rightarrow
v_{i}=\frac{R12\,v_{in} + R9\,v_{o}}{R9+R12}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(3)
$$

where

```
vin := The voltage at the C6, R9 node.
vo  := The op amp's output voltage
```

Using equations (1) and (3), and the op amp's open-loop voltage gain equation (4), solve for the op amp's output voltage \$v_{o}\$:

$$
A_{V} = \frac{v_{o}}{v_{n}-v_{i}}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(4)
\\[0.2in]
\rightarrow
v_{o} = \left ( \frac{ R11\,V_{CC}}{R10+R11} - \frac{R12\,v_{in}}{R9+R12} \right ) \left( \frac{A_{V}\,(R9+R12)}{A_{V}\,R9+R9+R12} \right )
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(5)
$$

Op amps typically have very large open loop voltage gain \$A_{V}\$; therefore, taking the limit of equation (5) as the open loop voltage gain \$A_{V}\$ tends to infinity yields the simplified model for the op amp's output voltage \$v_{o}\$ shown in equations (6) and (7):

$$
v_{o} \approx \lim_{A_{V}\rightarrow +\infty} v_{o}(A_{V}) = \left ( \frac{R11\,V_{CC}}{R10+R11}\ - \frac{R12\,v_{in}}{R9+R12} \right ) \left ( \frac{R9+R12}{R9} \right)
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(6)
\\[0.2in]
\rightarrow
v_{o} \approx \left ( \frac{R11}{R10+R11} \right ) \left ( \frac{R9+R12}{R9} \right ) V_{CC} - \frac{R12}{R9}\,v_{in}
\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(7)
$$

The left term on the right-hand side of equation (7) is the voltage offset that is added to the amplified \$v_{in}\$ signal.

The negative "voltage gain" term \$-R12\,V_{in}/R9\$ on the right-hand side of equation (7) means this is an inverting amplifier: the output signal's voltage is phase shifted 180 degrees compared to the input signal's voltage—i.e., when \$v_{in}\$ increases, \$v_{o}\$ decreases, and vice versa.